# How to make 2 power input but one DC output to my electric door lock?

Tags: switches

I originally have a video intercom system, however, since that system functionality is limited, I want to make it so that I can release the electric lock from anywhere over WiFi. So I bought a smart switch called **Sonoff mini R2**. This smart siwtch has an AC input of **110/220V** and an output of **110/220V** as well. But it passes power when a button is activated on the phone through an app.

So, first since the electric lock accept only **12V DC**, I have to convert the 220V coming from the smart switch by using converter (I'm going to use a laptop charger).

Now, the problem is when I connect the output of that charger to the electric lock, and I activate the button to push power, the voltage will also be sent to the **intercom system**, since that video intercom is also connected to the electric lock.

What I'm looking for are 2 things :

**1.** I don't want the smart switch to damage the video intercom by sending voltage to it.

**2.** I only want to activate one source of power at a time, either the smart switch or the video intercom.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatic battery backup from mains to battery bank on power outage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/608791/automatic-battery-backup-from-mains-to-battery-bank-on-power-outage)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using some Schottky diodes? This will probably be easiest in your case. Try to select a diode with a low Vf, and that can handle the current required by the load (the lock in this case). I personally like the 1Nxxx range, but make sure of the current rating. Then you want to put it in a circuit as follows:
[image]

If you do this, neither source can backfeed into the other, and if both happen to be on at the same time, it will "auto-select" the highest of the two voltages and the other will be "ignored".

P.S. Make sure you get a diode with a high enough current, otherwise you will let the magic smoke escape :)

Comment: Thanks, I have some concerns though. the door lock is outdoor and the whole circuitry is exposed to sunlight and heat. You think the diode will be just find if I put it outside with changing temperature? because the wires are literary just dangling at the back of the door. Also, should both of source 1 and 2 have a common ground?

Comment: For the diodes, I would put them in some heat-shrink. The UV might be bad for them, as well as the water. The heat is fine (they can operate up to around 100C+ usually). The two sources will have common ground, whether you connect them explicitly or not (they both go to the same load), so you may as well make it a good common ground...